# Changing monitor settings (Windows API)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

I've figured out how to get the display device settings and change the display device settings using the Windows API in Visual C++. (EnumDisplayDevice, EnumDisplaySettings, and ChangeDisplaySettings)

However, I have 4 different "monitors" if you will, that I would like to configure, but having different settings for multiple configurations.

One configuration involves settings extending the desktop to 3 monitors, with the 4th one being disabled, and the monitors set up like [Monitor 3] [Monitor 1 - Main] [Monitor 2].

The other configurations being [Monitor 3/4 - Duplicated] [Monitor 1 - Main] [Monitor 2] and [Monitor 3/4 - Main/Duplicated] with 1 and 2 being disabled.

Looking through the API documentation, there is something about DEVMODE POINTL dmPosition which I think refers to where the monitor is. Im wondering if the Windows API will automatically tell the monitors to duplicate or extend based on where the positioning of the screen is.

Has anyone done something similar to this and comment on how to go about doing this?

Comment: There is nothing in the WinAPI that controls the config for multiple monitors, such as which monitors participate in the virtual desktop.  This is done at the device driver level, using whatever GUI the driver provides.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Guess I'll have to look at the nVidia nvAPI.

Comment: @Chris O - How can Windows provide settings for configuring multiple monitors itself? I don't think that Windows uses nVidia's and ATI's APIs.

Comment: @fishbone SetDisplayConfig